# dotnet new target windows specific framework

Tags: .net-6.0, dotnet-new

Is there any way to get the [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) to use a platform specific target such as `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0`?

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

`dotnet new console --name HelloWindowsApi --framework net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0`

I'm attempting to create a new console application that can uses some [Windows Runtime APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance). So far the only way I've found to do it is to manually edit the project file after running `dotent new`.

Comment: Installing .NET6 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [KalleOlaviNiemitalo](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22804#issuecomment-981749013):

`dotnet new console --name CallWinRTConsole --framework net6.0 --target-framework-override net6.0-windows10.0.22000`